# introducing my DNS server to the TLD

Tags: domain-name-system

I've just bought a VPS and I had previously registered a domain.

On the domain control panel the only control I have is to set the domains name-servers.

The company I bought the VPS from do not provide free dns serving.

My question is how can I handle this situation? I've configured my server "nginx + php-fpm" and I've read articles related to setting up and running bind, but I couldn't think of anyway to introduce a prepared name-server to the TLDs (Any ways to introduce the prepared name-servers to the world).

Thanks very much.

Comment: You setup bind, and then you delegate the zone from the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've mis-read your question, you've answered it yourself: the only variable you can set on your control panel is the domain's name servers.  Take the IP addresses of your prepared server(s), and put them in there.

Comment: Actually I wasn't paying attention enough. My domain control panel had the interface for defining child name servers. Thank you very much.